# Windows 10 TFS 2015 ‘Json limit exceeded’ Error while compiling Fortran solutions

Tags: tfs, fortran, windows-10, tfs-2015, intel-fortran

I have configured a windows 10 machine to run XML build definition on TFS 2015. When it is running (None interactive mode) we get ‘Json limit exceeded’ error in the middle of the build. it's failing randomly different places of the build. what could be the reason for this?

It always failed, when it is compiling Fortran solutions. We have multiple Fortran solutions. It does not failed at any specific place. Sometimes while compiling the first and sometimes the other solutions. We can build those solutions with the command line (Using this command "devenv.com PathToFotranSolution /Build Release"). We are using 'Intel(R) Parallel Studio XE 2018 Update 1'. Everything is ok on Windows 7 build environment (Tested Windows 7 with TFS 2012 and TFS 2015. Both were OK).

[image: Error Log Screenshot 1]
[image: Error Log Screenshot 2]

Comment: this is too few information to help you. please provide code and samples

Comment: Could you share your build definition screenshot and entire log?

Comment: If you login your build agent machine, and run your project manually with MSBuild command, what result will you get?